# iterate over two numpy arrays return 1d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numpy

I often have a function that returns a single value such as a maximum or integral. I then would like to iterate over another parameter. Here is a trivial example using a parabolic. I don't think its broadcasting since I only want the 1D array. In this case its maximums. A real world example is the maximum power point of a solar cell as a function of light intensity but the principle is the same as this example.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-1,1) # sometimes this is read from file
parameters = np.array([1,12,3,5,6]) 
maximums = np.zeros_like(parameters)

for idx, parameter in enumerate(parameters):
    y = -x**2 + parameter
    maximums[idx] = np.max(y) # after I have the maximum I don't need the rest of the data.

print(maximums)
```

What is the best way to do this in Python/Numpy? I know one simplification is to make the function a **def** and then use np.vectorize but my understanding is it doesn't make the code any faster.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you? Consider accepting it, if it did. More info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1):

Extend one of those arrays to `2D` and then let [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) do those outer additions in a vectorized way -

```
maximums = (-x**2 + parameters[:,None]).max(1).astype(parameters.dtype)
```

Alternatively, with the explicit use of the outer addition method -

```
np.add.outer(parameters, -x**2).max(1).astype(parameters.dtype)
```